# PDF FontAwesome icon not showing

Tags: css

Using the CSS ::before tag, I am trying to use the FontAwesome PDF icon to show up an HTML page.

FontAwesome's cheat sheet says to use use this Unicode

```
 fa-file-pdf-o [&#xf1c1;]
```

So, I removed the "&#x" and replaced it with the  backslash "\", but it didn't work.

```
.pdf-icon li ::before {
    content: "\f1c1";
}
```

Only an icon placeholder displays, but not the PDF icon.

The directions on that page, says to "use on the desktop, install FontAwesome.otf, set it as the font in your application..."

Here's a link to their icon cheatsheet page: https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/cheatsheet/

So, I tried linking the FontAwesome.otf file to my web page, like this:

```
link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome/fonts/FontAwesome.otf"
```

I am pointing to this directory. Files are correct.
[image]

I have this rule in my CSS

```
.pdf-icon li ::before {
    content: "\f1c1";
}
```

...and I get this weird icon next the the PDF icon
[image]

**Solution:**
sebastianbrosc showed me this answer.  He hadded a font-family class to is [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/sebastianbrosch/9qjd8ows/) in order to call the fontAwesome font's unicode.  The unicode is considered a custom font. So I added font-family: FontAwesome to the rule, and it worked!

```
.pdf-icon li ::before {
    font-family:FontAwesome;
    content: "\f1c1";
}
```

Comment: Did u try adding their CDN to ur webpage?

Comment: this https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css

Comment: you can directly include their stylesheet into your code by adding <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"> to the head of your html page. That will allow you to directly make use of the classes defined within font awesome.

Comment: I am not using bootstrap; I wrote my own HTML and CSS.  Could you suggest another way?

Comment: it doesn't matter if you're using bootstrap or not. Including font awesome into your project would enable you to have that pdf icon, by simply adding a class "fa fa-file-pdf-o" . You can have a look at the plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/r5FLCN?p=preview

Comment: I linked the otf file but am still getting a weird icon next the PDF icon. See image. http://i.stack.imgur.com/1BPhK.png

Answer (score 2):

You should add the folder from the following to your project: https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/tree/master/fonts

On CSS you have to add the following code and change the paths to the font files:

```
@font-face{
    font-family:'FontAwesome';
    src:url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eotv=4.4.0');
    src:url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.4.0') format('embedded-opentype'), 
        url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.4.0') format('woff2'), 
        url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.4.0') format('woff'), 
        url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.4.0') format('truetype'), 
        url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.4.0#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
    font-weight:normal;
    font-style:normal;
}
```

A very simple solution is to add the stylesheet (with the css above) from CDN to your website:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Here you can find an example with your cheatsheet and a unicode solution for CSS (both using the foundation css from cdn): http://jsfiddle.net/sebastianbrosch/9qjd8ows/

Comment: Where did you add the example?

Comment: replace `link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome/fonts/FontAwesome.otf"` with `link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"`

Comment: That's it!  You added the rule font-family:FontAwesome; to the class. I didn't know that. where is that documented?

Comment: there is no documentation for that, because font-awesome is a framework to use this icons with css classes. But if you add a custom font to a website you have to set the custom font-family. If you don't set the font-family the browser takes the default font!

Comment: You wrote: "But if you add a custom font to a website you have to set the custom font-family. If you don't set the font-family the browser takes the default font!"  Makes perfect sense, now; but I wouldn't have thought of it. Thank you! :)